# Problems with last modification of file

Tags: java, file, date, calendar, last-modified

i dont get the correct last modification from a class inheriting from the File class.
My method is this:

```
public Date getLastModification() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(lastModified());
    Date dateRepresentation = cal.getTime();
    return dateRepresentation;
}
```

When i call this method in the toString, this always prints Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970.
I reviewed the api of file and i dont understand why this happens. Can you help me with correct implementation?

Comment: can you show code of lastModified()?

Comment: i dont define the method lastModified(), because is a method of File, i search this in API

Answer (score 0):

Your logic works for me. You should ensure that your file exists

```
FileTest test = new FileTest("test.txt");
System.out.println("Existing:" + test.getLastModification());

FileTest test2 = new FileTest("");
System.out.println("Not existing: " + test2.getLastModification());
```

output is:

```
Sat Mar 11 10:24:39 CET 2017
File does not exist
Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
```

with `FileTest` like:

```
public class FileTest extends File {


    public FileTest(String pathname) {
        super(pathname);
    }

    public Date getLastModification() {
        if(!exists()){
            System.out.println("File does not exist");
        }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(lastModified());
        return cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for that is the **File is not existing in the path for which you have created your custom File object** and hence in the code `cal.setTimeInMillis(lastModified());`  `lastModified()`is returning 0 and so you are seeing the initialized local date of the Calendar API.